# How can I move a single line of text up by 10px or 15px using CSS?

Tags: html, css, text, fonts, stylesheet

I have a single line of text in my footer of my html/php website, next to it is a twitter button. The problem is visually it doesn't look right as the button is out of line with the line of text. I have tried evrything I can think of from line-hight to padding, margins and just plan height but nothing is getting the line of text where I want it to be. I have tried minus values to like 3em and -3em.

Can anyone think of a way to force the line up by roughly 10px - 15px?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot or code snippet? That will help illustrate your problem.

Comment: DO NOT USE THIS TAG. Use [css] for CSS related issues and [xslt] for XSLT related issues instead. - [stylesheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
bottom: 15px;
```

Comment: Thank you! You nailed it first time, been struggling with this for an hour :)

Answer (score 0):

```
display: block;
margin-bottom: 15px;
```